# Spinner getSelectedItem() return worng position

Tags: android

I'm getting error when i use

`String a=(String)spinner.getSelectedItem();`

log is:

```
      java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 220, size is 7
      at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
      at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
```

but my list has not 7 item!!

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    // your code here
 String selectedValue=arralist.get(position);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
    // your code here
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

Use this

Answer (score 0):

Spinner Position start with 0 and spinner taken default select position.

You need to stop spinner choose default select position Just use Boolean function

Just Initiate `private boolean isSpinnerInitial = true;`

Inside on create method

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


            if (isSpinnerInitial) {
                    isSpinnerInitial = false;
                } else {
              String position = String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
             }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```